# Python - Why does aws lambda run multiple threads so slowly?

Tags: python, multithreading, aws-lambda

i am using AWS Lambda to run a python code

```
def get_likers(link):
    #scrapes a site

def lambda_handler(event, context):


    text = #gets link from a telegram bot message

    checkt = threading.Thread(target=get_likers, args=[text])
    checkt1 = threading.Thread(target=get_likers, args=["here's a link"])
    checkt2 = threading.Thread(target=get_likers, args=["here's a link"])
    checkt3 = threading.Thread(target=get_likers, args=["here's a link"])
    checkt4 = threading.Thread(target=get_likers, args=["here's a link"])


    checks = []
    checks.append(checkt)
    checks.append(checkt1)
    checks.append(checkt2)
    checks.append(checkt3)
    checks.append(checkt4)


    for thread in checks:
        thread.start()



    for thread in checks:
        thread.join()


return {'statusCode': 200}
```

It should run the threads simoultaneously and finish fast, but while if i do this with just 1 thread it takes 3 seconds, with 5 threads it takes 7 seconds and with 20 threads 60 + seconds. Why is this happening? Each thread is kinda light and the data to scrape is the same for each thread

Comment: Also, ensure you are using a rather powerful processor. Higher function memory on the function == better underlying processor for your function. For lower function memory, you are likely to land a single threaded processor.

Comment: @ShreyasGaonkar in the logs it says that the max used memory is 96 Mb, whie i allocated something more. Increasing the allocated memory will still help?

Comment: It will, even though we might not be using the physical memory, the underlying CPU will change and its performance is directly related to the set function memory: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

"For example, choosing 256MB of memory allocates approximately twice as much CPU power to your Lambda function as requesting 128MB of memory and half as much CPU power as choosing 512MB of memory."

Answer (score 0):

CPython threads I/O bound tasks well, but CPU bound tasks poorly.

And if you add one CPU bound thread to an otherwise I/O bound set of threads, they all start having problems.

I don't know the AWS Lambda specifics, but this could be what you're seeing.

Note that Python, the language, threads fine.  It's implementations like CPython and Pypy that do not thread well.  Jython and IronPython thread well.

Comment: Do you think allocating more memory to the function could help? (Aws lambda gives me more CPU power proportionally to the allocated memory)

Comment: Maybe, but I'd probably try https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html or at least https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process first.

Comment: You think multiprocessing would be better than multithreading?

Comment: @GitJorgo Likely.

Comment: Now i am doing it with multiprocessing, but to get data from 20 pages in multiprocessing it takes around 20 seconds. How can i make this faster?

Comment: The standard response to "how can I make it faster" is to profile the code to identify the hotspots, and address them.